# Разъясните неизвестный объект

Tags: java

Здравствуйте, выясните, бо при разборе кода, никак не могу понять что это такое, а ошибку не показывает, спасибо:

```
public class BDtable {
    BDtable(){

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         //Это...
         new BDtable();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Может я чего-то не понимаю в вопросе, но строка new BDtable(); - это создание объекта класса BDtable без сохранения ссылки на него в переменную. Так обычно создают окна интерфейса в методе main, когда от него нужно только создать этот объект окна, а какие-либо методы этого объекта не используются. Поправьте меня, если я не прав.